# How to copy data between two tables in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two table with different column like this:

```
table1
(
    _id,
    title,
    name,
    number,
    address
)

table2
(
    _id,
    phone,
    name,
    address
)
```

How can I copy data 'name', 'address' from table1 to table2.

And my question have two situation:

- First: table1, table2 in the same database file
- Second: table1 in data1.db file, table2 in data2.db file

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Copying in SQL works like so:

```
insert into table2 (name, address)
select name, address
from table1
```

If the values of the column `id_` are the same, you need to insert and update

```
insert into table2 (name, address)
select name, address
from table1 t1
where not exists (select * from table2 t2 where t1._id = t2._id)
;
update table2 t2 name = (select name from table1 t2 where t1._id = t2._id)
;
update table2 t2 address = (select address from table1 t2 where t1._id = t2._id)
```

If you need to copy the columns between databases, you first export them into a file (use any format you like, for example CSV) and then merge that file into the second database manually since you can't write an SQL which says "use these sqlite structures".

Comment: Why not just insert the ids the first time around?

Comment: @Ramin: My code inserts all the ids the first time around. If you try to insert ids from `table2` that already exist, you will get errors. So the two update statements will copy the non-id fields for all existing ids.

Comment: In the case where I am resetting my primary key ids (from random numbers to 1,2,3,...,n (integers starting from 1)), the first piece of code really helps.