# In sqlite3: copy a column from one table to another table

Tags: sqlite

There are several other stackoverflow inquiries about this topic, but none of them have a satisfactory answer.

I have a table BeerReviews, which is missing a column (review_text), and another table BeerReviewsWithText which is missing a different column (brewery_name). Otherwise the table rows are ordered the same way, so I would like to simply append the brewery_name column from BeerReviews into BeerReviewsWithText.

I launch sqlite3 as:

```
sqlite3 beer_rewiews_with_text.sqlite
```

Then I attach the beer reviews table via:

```
attach 'beer_reviews.sqlite' as BR
```

I added an empty column to BeerReviewsWithText via:

```
alter table BeerReviewsWithText add column beer_brewername varchar;
```

[Multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029391/copy-column-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-sqlite/5033489#5033489) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361921/select-into-statement-in-sqlite/2361961#2361961) questions suggest using insert to fill the column, but this appends new rows to the table, populating only the beer_brewername column.

```
insert into BeerReviewsWithText(beer_brewername) select brewery_name from BeerReviews;
```

Instead, an update seems to fill in the null values, but when I run the following (similar to [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559789/copy-data-between-two-table-in-sqlite)) all of the beer_brewername values are identical:

```
update BeerReviewsWithText set beer_brewername=(select brewery_name from BR.BeerReviews);
```

This seems like strange behavior since I get the expected list of brewery names when I run:

```
select brewery_name from BR.BeerReviews limit 50;
```

I'm new to sqlite, so can someone explain what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 12):

When you use a subquery as an expression, like this:

```sql
UPDATE BeerReviewsWithText
SET beer_brewername = (SELECT brewery_name
                       FROM BR.BeerReviews)
```

then only the first record returned by the subquery will be used.

You must write a subquery that returns a single record, but a different record for each record in the outer table. This is called a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE BeerReviewsWithText
SET beer_brewername = (SELECT brewery_name
                       FROM BR.BeerReviews
                       WHERE ID = BeerReviewsWithText.ID)
```

(This assumes that you have an `ID` column as primary key.)

Comment: OK, so I'm running the following which is taking an _incredibly_ long time:
    `update main.BeerReviewsWithText set beer_brewername=(select brewery_name from BR.BeerReviews where brewery_id = main.BeerReviewsWithText.beer_brewerid);`

The brewery_id and beer_brewerid fields all match up row to row, but aren't unique identifiers across rows since each brewery has many reviews. Hopefully that's OK?

Comment: As long as the brewery ID uniquely identifies the brewery name, this is OK. For efficient lookups, you need an index on the `brewery_id` column.

Comment: After adding indeces to both id columns, the update ran in a reasonable time. I'll have to read a bit more about how these speed things up. Thanks again!